# How can i capture data using the for command from a text file and set it as a variable (windows command prompt)

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

Situation

Using Diskpart I can get DETAIL DISK info which looks like this:

```
Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.17763.1

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: PC

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

Samsung SSD 960 EVO 500GB
Disk ID: {00000}
Type   : NVMe
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 0
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1D00)#PCI(0000)#NVME(P00T00L00)
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : Yes
Pagefile Disk  : Yes
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : Yes
Clustered Disk  : No

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------

Leaving DiskPart...
```

The text i want to capture is "Samsung SSD 960 EVO 500GB"
Obviously, when i run this on a system with a different drive, this info will change, so it could be a Western Digital or Seagate drive etc instead.

I was thinking of using:

```
for /f "skip=7 delims=" %g in (disk1.txt) do set disk1=%g
```

However, this captures everything below and the final bit of data is stored ("Leaving DiskPart...") as the variable. Not the first value. How can i fix this? There must be something simple i haven't thought of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are dead set on running this from the command line, I think this would be your only option.

```
set "disk1=" & for /f "skip=7 delims=" %g in (disk1.txt) do IF NOT DEFINED disk1 set "disk1=%g"
```

But since you tagged this question with Batch File then you could use a GOTO command.

```
for /f "skip=7 delims=" %%g in (disk1.txt) do (set "disk1=%%g" & goto done)
:done
```

Answer (score 2):

Would you prefer to go directly to the source and skip the text processing?

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%s IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "(Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_DiskDrive).Model"') DO (SET "DISK1=%%s")
```

Good idea, @LotPings.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%s IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Disk).FriendlyName"') DO (SET "DISK1=%%s")
```

Given that this may return an array, choose which one by using the `-Number` parameter.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%s IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Disk -Number 0).FriendlyName"') DO (SET "DISK1=%%s")
```

This is even easier once you start writing PowerShell scripts instead of .bat files. PowerShell is clearly the course Microsoft has set.

```
$disk1 = (Get-Disk -Number 0).FriendlyName
```

Comment: Or `(Get-Disk).FriendlyName` or `(Get-PhysicalDisk).FriendlyName`

Answer (score 1):

You could also utilise `WMIC` to do this, which unlike the `DiskPart` method does not require to be *Run as administrator and does not require the output to be written to a file and read back in to be parsed*:

```bat
@For /F "Skip=1Delims=" %%A In ('WMIC DiskDrive Where "Index=1" Get Model')Do @For /F Tokens^=* %%B In ("%%A")Do @Set "_=%%B"
```

To check if it has worked, add the following line below it:

```bat
@Set _&Pause
```